# State and behavior verification in the same unit test - is it clean?

Tags: unit-testing, junit

In every book is written that unit test should in the assert/verify section check only one thing. And in the same time ther is a example like this below

```
  @Test
  public void shouldReturnSomethingAndExecuteExternalComponent(){

    // Given
    ExternalComponent externalComponent = EasyMock.createStrictMock(ExternalComponent.class);
    configureMock(externalComponent);

    // When
    Result result = objectUnderTest.foo();

    //Then
    Result expectedResult = ...
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult, result);
    externalComponent.verify(); 

  }
```

In this case, behavior  is checked (executing of externalComponent - **externalComponent.verify()**) and the state of the object after the test("**assertEquals(expectedResult, result)**"). Is it clean that two verifications are mixed in one test? what do you think? Or it should be splitted on two test ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test should be split into two tests

- shouldReturnSomething()
- shouldExecuteSomething()

If you use [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) instead of EasyMock then the shouldExecuteSomething will look nicer, because you don't have to define the verified behaviour of the external component before executing the test.

```
@Test
public void shouldExecuteSomething(){
  // Given
  ExternalComponent externalComponent = mock(ExternalComponent.class);
  objectUnderTest.use(externalComonent)

  // When
  objectUnderTest.foo();

  //Then
  verify(externalComponent).someMethod(); 
}
```

Comment: +1:  Curious that it sat for 7 hours and then got two simultaneous agreeing answers!

Comment: Next time we will even avoid the 15 seconds delay ;-)

Comment: Doesn't this end up in duplicating the preparation code of the test? ( the "given" part for example). In this case would you extract the common code to a method?

Comment: Yes, but I think code duplication in tests should be handled differently than in production code. For the sake of readability code duplication in tests is sometimes helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be terribly upset by seeing that, as it's not an extreme case of checking too much in one test, but I'd be inclined to split it:

```
  @Test
  public void shouldReturnSomething(){

    // Given
    ExternalComponent externalComponent = EasyMock.createStrictMock(ExternalComponent.class);
    configureMock(externalComponent);

    // When
    Result result = objectUnderTest.foo();

    //Then
    Result expectedResult = ...
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult, result);

  }


  @Test
  public void shouldExecuteExternalComponent(){

    // Given
    ExternalComponent externalComponent = EasyMock.createStrictMock(ExternalComponent.class);
    configureMock(externalComponent);

    // When
    Result result = objectUnderTest.foo();

    //Then
    externalComponent.verify(); 

  }
```